# Two-Band k.p Model is not Hermitian for imaginary wavevectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, linear-algebra, complex-numbers, quantum-tunneling

In [E. O. Kane](http://dx.doi.org.proxy.library.cornell.edu/10.1016/0022-3697(60)90035-4)'s original work on Zener Tunneling, he uses a two-band $k\cdot p$ model for the semiconductor bandstructure:

$$H=\begin{pmatrix}E_g+\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m_0}&(\hbar/m)kp\\(\hbar/m)kp&\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m_0}\end{pmatrix}$$

Moving along real $k$, one sees a conduction and valence band repelling each other via the momentum matrix element.  But if you step onto the imaginary $k$ axis, there is a curve stretching through the band-gap to connect the extrema of the conduction and valence bands.  These solutions for imaginary $k$ can be used to [represent surface states](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0370-1328/81/2/311), and they provide a smooth path for a semiclassical wavepacket to "tunnel" between bands while always having a well-defined position and wavevector.

But the above Hamiltonian is non-Hermitian when one plugs in complex values for $k$.  (And if you make it Hermitian by conjugating one of the off-diagonal terms, the connection between the bands disappears.)  So these spatially decaying states (which all have real energies within a certain $k$ range) are not actually eigenvectors of a Hermitian Hamiltonian...what are they?

I suppose I'm missing something fundamental about this procedure, but I don't see why this famous model assumes and works with a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian and what that means for the computed eigenvalues*.  Has anyone come across any physics papers that address the subtle aspects of this?

---

.* For instance, I noticed that, at least in the range where all eigenvalues are real, the eigenvectors must be non-orthogonal (otherwise this non-Hermitian matrix could be real-diagonalized, which is a contradiction.)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think that the matrix will have left and right eigenvectors. And then a wild guess that one of these eigenvector sets will represent asymptotically diverging solutions, and the other decaying solutions.

Comment: The Hamiltonian $H$ is Hermitian while $e^{\kappa z} H e^{-\kappa z}$ does not have to be hermitian. The eigenvalues are real as long as the wave function is normalizable. For a half infinite surface $z>0$ this means a solution $\propto e^{-\kappa z}$ with $\kappa>0$.

Comment: The lower left entry of your Hamiltonian should have $p^\dagger$ instead, or in position represenation, a minus sign.

Comment: @MikaelKuisma The eigenstates of this matrix represent Bloch waves of whatever $k$ you plug in ($k$ being simply a parameter of the Hamiltonian), so the right eigenvectors represent decaying or growing solutions purely based on your choice of $\pm i k$.

Comment: @Praan I'm not sure what you're talking about with the $e^{kz}He^{-kz}$ expression, could you say more about where that came from?  Also, the above matrix comes directly from Eq 19 of the cited paper.  And the author says $p$, which is simply a number (momentum matrix element between Bloch basis states), can be taken pure real.  One can't put in a minus sign there, else the matrix would be nonhermitian for real $k$.